# clickhouse uniqCombinedMerge different queries

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have two tables: test_a and test_b, both are with a column of uniqCombinedState to calculate number of users of different time window, how to get intersection count of users query from test_a and test_b using uniqCombinedMerge.

table_a create sql:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_db.test_a 
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
PARTITION BY intDiv(timestamp, 7200000)
ORDER BY (version) AS
SELECT
    version_n,
    max(timestamp) AS timestamp,
    uniqCombinedState(uid) AS value
FROM test_db.test_origin
GROUP BY (version)
```

table_b create sql:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_db.test_b 
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
PARTITION BY intDiv(timestamp, 3600000)
ORDER BY (version) AS
SELECT
    version_n,
    max(timestamp) AS timestamp,
    uniqCombinedState(uid) AS value
FROM test_db.test_origin
GROUP BY (version)
```

I try to merge uniqCombinedState(uid) query from test_b and test_a,
but how to write the query sql? I try to write with 'with select', but it doesn't work.

sql that i want like(but it doesn't work):

```
with (select uniqCombinedState(`value`) as value from test_db.`test_a`  where `timestamp` between 1637505413789 and 1637505431789 as first ) 
select uniqCombinedMerge(`value`, first.value) as value from  test_db.`test_b` where `timestamp` between 1637505413789 and 1637505431789
```

Comment: you cannot get intersection only union https://youtu.be/b9MeoOtAivQ?t=2809

Comment: i get the intersection using union, like Count(a) + Count(b) - UnionCount(a,b), im trying to use bitmap, groupBitmapAnd may solve my problem, thanks a lot